# LINK: fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'odbc.lib

Tags: python, sql-server

I am new to python. I want to set SQL Server as the data source of python codes. It seems that I need to first install pyodbc. I used the command below to install pyodbc.

"pip install pyodbc==1".

I got a few error messages. I solved them by editing Path and Include environment variables. But now I am stuck at a new error:

"LINK: fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'odbc.lib'".

I found the odbc.lib is located at the following two folders. 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86.

I searched and read similar questions in stackoverflow. It seems that I should add the path to environment variables. I added both paths to the Path and Include environment variables but these do not address the error.

Your help is truly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you've taken the right steps. For changes to the `PATH` to take effect, the command window needs to be relaunched. Sometimes I've restarted my computer fully to make sure `PATH` changes flow through to every process. Could you just try and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found that this problem can be solved by add the LIB and LIBPATH environment variables.